# Not able to capture parameters passed through GET Request

Tags: java, web, httprequest

I am trying to build the Referral functionlity flow for my application. I capture the  referral ID from the URL using request parameter. Here is the code snippet :

```
if (null != request.getParameter("refId")
            && "" != request.getParameter("refId")) {

        request.getSession().setAttribute("referenceId",
                request.getParameter("refId"));

} else {

        request.getSession().removeAttribute("referenceId");
}
```

Thr url for my application is `http://shoponline.com/?refId=34523423`

However, the referral ID never gets caught from the URL. I tried printing `request.getParamter("refId")` to the console,but it always displays null.

Am I missing something?

Comment: In your question there's no problem, but just double check your URL to see if your parameter `refId` match case with your java code

Comment: I cross checked it. The paramater `refId` matches case with my java code.

Comment: You know that `"" != X` is comparing the memory address, right? It would be better if you replace that with `!"".equals(X)`.

Answer (score 1):

You not showing enough of your configuration. I'm concerned about the fact that the URL doesn't have anything after the "http://shoponline.com/" It may be because your index.html (or index.jsp) page is doing a "forward" to your servlet and the request parameter is not included. In short, there is no reason the code won't work, so you need to look at how your web-application is configured.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly use the URL like this , It should work:

```
http://shoponline.com?refId=34523423
String refID=request.getParameter("refId");
out.println(refID);
```

Do little bit changes as per your requirement.